# How to add an EPPlus Sheet to an OpenXML document?

Tags: excel, openxml, epplus

I would like to add a Sheet I've created using EPPlus to an OpenXml document (OpenXml.Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument). Is there a fairly straightforward way to do this?

Unfortunately opening up the excel document using EPPlus and adding the sheet, then saving, causes issues with excel file, so I'd like to try to add the sheet using OpenXml.

Comment: What's the issue with adding a sheet through EPPlus? I've used it a lot and never had any issues with it